# Primefaces callback with JSON as callback parameter

Tags: json, primefaces

I am trying to pass Json as callback parameter. Can anyone correct the javascript to get the values from the json object?

javascript

```
function renderTopic(xhr,status,args){
        alert("iam In renderTopic");
        var topicObject = $.parseJSON(args.topicJSON);
        for(var x in topicObject){
            alert(x.topicBody);
        };
    }
```

Server side

```
   jGenerator.writeFieldName("topicBody");
            jGenerator.writeStartArray();
                 ...............
            jGenerator.close();
             context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
             System.out.println("JSON output in string "+out.toString())
```

xhtml

```
<p:commandLink action="#{topicController.listAllTopics}"
                id="topicListAllCmdLink" value="" oncomplete="javascript:renderTopic(xhr, status,args)"/>
```

http response

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[4091946826703479326:-2361306414195161728]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"topicJSON":"{\"topicBody\":[\"Test10\",\"Test22\",\"Test4\",\"Test11\"]}"}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: @SLaks i just edited and added the server side code. You can see the http response output having json format

Comment: JSF is a component based framework, what are you doing is not the JSF way ...
What you want to do with the JSON?
Maybe there is a best way to achive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing seems to be ok. Do you see any error? or any output that you can tell us about.

See this link to get a better description:
[Best method for passing Data from Java/JSF2 bean to Javascript/jQuery Components as return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930047/best-method-for-passing-data-from-java-jsf2-bean-to-javascript-jquery-components)

Comment: I believe it is failing at parsing the jquery since it has backslash before double quote.

Comment: How to avoid primefaces from prepending "\" in the json output?

Comment: are you sure that primefaces add those backslashes? could you please paste the code where you generate and append the json to callback, i see the current code is not complete.