# p:graphicImage with viewscoped

Tags: jsf, primefaces

page:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{testController.QR}" />
```

testController bean:

```
private StreamedContent QR;
private ByteArrayOutputStream rawQR;

public StreamedContent getQR() {
    if (rawQR != null) {
        rawQR = QRCode.from("test").to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawQR.toByteArray());
        QR = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
        return QR;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display a QR image on the page.

with SessionScoped the above code works, but with ViewScoped it displays a broken image icon, i need my bean to be ViewScoped. What am i missing here?

QR Reference: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/

Comment: possible duplicate of [ManagedBean return null to graphicImage in Primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651248/managedbean-return-null-to-graphicimage-in-primefaces)