# Preprocess/postprocess a bean action method from p:remoteCommand inside composite

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, action, composite-component

I have the following scenario:

JSF composite component with complex JavaScript, which I'd like to refresh partially by JavaScript with a new values from a backing bean (backing bean of a page which uses this composite component, not backing component `@FacesComponent`).
*I don't want to make full update because it's complex JavaScript plugin and it will unacceptably break [UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).*

I get values from backing component `@FacesComponent` by using Primefaces's [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) with callback as described here [Best method for passing Data from Java/JSF2 bean to Javascript/jQuery Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930047/best-method-for-passing-data-from-java-jsf2-bean-to-javascript-jquery-components)

I know that it's some abuse of JSF but would like to encapsulate all the functionality in a single unit and don't mess with a [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) If you can advice another nice solution how to encapsulate such complex jQuery plugin (for sake of clarity we are talking about [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/), I know that Primefaces has its own implementation of this component but its functionality insufficient for my requirement so, I was need to make my own implementation) which highly related on ajax callbacks with parameters you're highly welcome to share it here.

My question is how to update values in a backing component `@FacesComponent` from backing bean by using JavaScript? Currently I involved in the following chain of events:

1. calling from Javascript `<p:remoteCommand>` with parameters which passed to backing component `@FacesComponent` to be dispatched later in `AjaxBehaviorEvent`

   **JavaScript**:

   ```
          refreshEvents([
                 {name:'start', value:start.format()}, 
                 {name:'end', value:end.format()}
          ]);
   ```

   **JSF code**:

   ```
    <p:remoteCommand name="refreshValues" oncomplete="loadValues()"  action="#{cc.refreshLocal()}" process="@this"/>
   ```

   Parameters which I passed stored in a backing component by using

   ```
   getStateHelper().put(...);
   ```
2. jQuery event dispatched from composite component by following JavaScript code:

   ```
       var hiddenField = $(document.getElementById(variables.hiddenId));
       hiddenField.trigger("keypress");
   ```
3. In composite component's overridden method `public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event)` I add to this `AjaxBehaviorEvent` property which I stored before, in a 1st step and dispatch it forward.
4. Dispatched event from composite component "captured" in a page where composite component nested and performed `process` on this component:

   ```
   <p:ajax event="refreshEvent" process="@this"  listener="#{bean.refreshEvents}"/>
   ```

   in `#{bean.refreshEvent}` method I perform request to `@EJB` bean and load data.
5. On callback from step 1 called again  by `loadValues()`

   `<p:remoteCommand name="loadValues" action="#{cc.getLocalData()}"  oncomplete="updateValues(xhr, status, args);"/>`
6. In a backing component's method `#{cc.getLocalData()}` I add a callback parameter by using:

   `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("param", ...);`
7. function `updateValues(xhr, status, args)` from step 5 get in `args` this param's values and performs actual update.

So, my general question is it possible to simplify this process and how?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the latest PF snapshot or elite release. It has extender functionality. And if you do use PF, why not download the source, create a patch and submit it?

Comment: There're two problems. First I'm not there yet, I've a lot to learn to make it. Second, due to policy of my job it isn't simple to share our code, not impossible but not simple. Actually I just looked at the source code. I think that all I need I can do by overriding `protected void encodeEvents(FacesContext context, Schedule schedule) `, possible it isn't such difficult as I thought, thank you for your hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a little overcomplicated. In total 3 ajax requests to just perform an action and a backing component passing data forth and back via the view state.

Your primary goal appears to be able to declare a bean action method as composite component attribute which should then be invoked by a `<p:remoteCommand>` inside the composite and return the desired model entity based on the passed-in parameters, preferably with some pre- and post-processing.

You can use `<cc:attribute method-signature>` in the composite interface to declare a method expression attribute:

```
<cc:interface componentType="yourComposite">
    <cc:attribute name="eventListener" method-signature="com.example.Entity method(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
```

Which can be used in the template client as below:

```
<my:composite ... eventListener="#{bean.eventListener}" />
```

```
public Entity eventListener(String start, String end) {
    // ...
    return entity;
}
```

The composite implementation can look like this:

```
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <p:remoteCommand name="refreshEvents" 
        process="@this" action="#{cc.processEventListener}"
        oncomplete="updateValues(xhr, status, args)" />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

The `#{cc.processEventListener}` method can obtain the `eventListener` attribute as a `MethodExpression` and invoke it as below, along with some pre- and post-processing:

```
public void processEventListener() {
    String start = getRequestParameter("start");
    String end = getRequestParameter("end");
    // ...
    MethodExpression method = (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("eventListener");
    Entity entity = (Entity) eventListener.invoke(getFacesContext().getELContext(), new Object[] { start, end });
    // ...
    addCallbackParam("param", entityAsJSON);
}
```

Now it's only 1 ajax request "as usual".

Comment: But for this scenario I should create json in webbean and I'd like to encapsulate all this functionality (POJO -> json) in a backing component, is it possible to implement and stay with 1 ajax request?